# Scala case class not return data

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

I used mongoDB and scala in my project using [salat](https://github.com/novus/salat) library and my model contains as :

```
case class ApplicationGroupModel(
  @Key("_id") id: ObjectId,
  devicesData: List[ApplicationDevicesData]
  )
case class ApplicationDevicesData(
  hostId: Option[String],
  tcpPorts: List[Int] = List.empty,
  applications: List[String] = List.empty)
object ApplicationGroupModel extends ModelCompanion[ApplicationGroupModel, ObjectId] {

  val collection = ScalaMongoFactory.database(collectionName)
  val dao = new SalatDAO[ApplicationGroupModel, ObjectId](collection = collection) {}
  def apply(rawData: JsValue): ApplicationGroupModel = {
    val devicesDataList = getTcpData(rawData)
    ApplicationGroupModel(new ObjectId,devicesDataList)
  }

 private def getTcpData(rawData: JsValue): List[ApplicationDevicesData] = {
        //function body
        //return List of ApplicationDevicesData

  }
```

and in controller I call model as :

```
val allData = ApplicationGroupModel.findOneById(new ObjectId("556c23b244aef072afcb6d50")).toList
```

If I print `allData` it shows following output :

```
ApplicationGroupModel(556c23b244aef072afcb6d50,List(ApplicationDevicesData(Some(127.0.0.1),List(),List()), ApplicationDevicesData(Some(127.0.0.1),List(),List()), ApplicationDevicesData(Some(localhost),List(),List()))))
```

but If I call `model` like this :

```
val allData = ApplicationGroupModel.collection.findOneByID(new ObjectId("556c23b244aef072afcb6d50")).toList
```

and print `allData` then output as :

```
List({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "556c23b244aef072afcb6d50"} ,  "devicesData" : [ { "hostId" : "127.0.0.1" , "tcpPort" : [ 80 , 22 , 443] ,   "application" : [ "ABC"]} , { "hostId" : "127.0.0.1" , "tcpPort" : [ 22] ,   "application" : [ "XYZ"]} , { "hostId" : "localhost" , "tcpPort" : [ 5000 , 4100 , 22 , 80] ,   "application" : [ "ABCD"]}]})
```

I don't know why my `model` find Method not return `tcpPorts` with values it always empty lists same for `applications` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple naming problem.  Your model object specifies `tcpPorts` and `applications` (plural) but your Mongo document has `tcpPort` and `application` (singular).  Fix one or the other, or (not recommended since it will make your hand-written queries a pain, but it fixes your immediate problem) use `@Key` with each field to map the singular to the plural.